Migration: how to replace old definer
I'm facing the same issue as the one solved here: Migration error: “The user specified as a definer does not exist”. However I have to consider the following points:

the database it way to huge to sed into it (i.e. replacing the old definer by the new one)
database access configuration is no more local but remote
the problem occurs even when I try to flush the cache from cli (cv flush) : DELETE FROM civicrm_queue  WHERE (  civicrm_queue.id = 1 ) [nativecode=1449 ** The user specified as a definer ('old_definer'@'localhost') does not exist]

Is there a clean way to achieve this migration process?

CiviCRM: 5.75
Drupal: 10.3.1


can you rebuild the trigger http://example.org/civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1&triggerRebuild=1

Thank you Pradeep Nayak, I already tried and got the same query's error: DELETE FROM civicrm_queueWHERE (civicrm_queue.id = 1 ).

I would redump without triggers and import them back
mysqldump -uusername -p db_name --skip-triggers > dumbname.mysql
    
drop database db_name;
    
create database db_name;
    
mysql -uusername -p db_name < dumbname.mysql

Run the rebuild trigger command http://example.org/civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1&triggerRebuild=1

Thank you Pradeep Nayak! I will skip triggers next time. For this one I removed the triggers based on this SO answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/30339930
